# C like while in java with integer?

Tags: java, c, syntax

is it possible in java to have a C like syntax for this:

```
            int counter = 10;
            while(counter){
                    System.out.println(counter--);
            }
```

In C it is working very well to count until the counter is 0... do i really have to write

```
            int counter = 10;
            while(counter!=0){
                    System.out.println(counter--);
            }
```

?

Comment: That code is **screaming**, "I will be a bug when I grow up!"

Comment: @Mehrdad - I'm SO going to steal that from you.

Comment: @Brian: Forgot to mention... © 2011

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, java requires a `boolean` in a `while` condition.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that treating all conditions as boolean conditions in C is proper programming practice, as it makes the code more readable and less bug-prone. This is required by MISRA-C and all other such de-facto coding standards.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use a while loop here in Java or C.  This is clearer IMHO.

```
for(int counter = 10; counter > 0; counter--)
    System.out.println(counter);
```

Comment: +1 Much better imho since it makes the scope of the counter smaller.

Answer (score 0):

The best place to clarify that kind of question is Java Language Specification.

Related to your question please refer [The while Statement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.12)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do have to write that. As @Thomas Jungblut said, Java requires a boolean in the while condition.

This is a good thing. In plain English, what does "while `counter`" mean? Nothing. It only has meaning if you say "while `counter` is nonzero". Java forces you to say what you mean.

Comment: Meh. In `c` it means (in plain english) "While counter is a positive number". Different isn't right or wrong. Much like translating spoken languages, often there's a context involved. In this case, it's like when there's no direct translation; c doesn't have boolean.

Comment: @Brian Roach Actually it means "While counter is nonzero". This sort of subtle distinction is not an issue in Java because it forces you to present a boolean which can only have one of two values. I take your point that you can't always read it in English, though.

Comment: True enough - I meant in the OP's example, but you're right I should have said "non-zero".

Comment: While I agree that there is a meaning in C, I also think it is a good practice to explicitly evaluate the condition, because the maintainer who comes after you will not necessarily know C very well but they will likely be able to evaluate a Boolean condition. (Unless the next programming